# HttpURLConnection .getInputStream() stop working

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, inputstreamreader

I'm creating an Android project where the ActivityMain connects to a PHP file (in a local server, localhost) using HttpURLConnection;

I have a problem with the following code line:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
```

When I run the project, the application stops at this point, without return any error.

Where is the problem?

I report the code part here:

```
public class SendToLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

//private EditText usernameField,passwordField;
private String username, password;
private Context context;
private Boolean loggato = false;
JSONObject rspJ;


public SendToLogin(String usr, String psw, Context c) {
    username = usr;
    password = psw;
    context = c;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String link = params[0] + "?username=" + username.toString() + "&password=" + password.toString();
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String result = "";
    String line = "";
    try {

        url = new URL(link);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();


        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + "\n";
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return result;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    String result = s;
    JSONObject reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new JSONObject(result);
        String query_result = reader.getString("msg");
        if(query_result.toString() == "ok")
            new ListaUtenti();
        else {
            Toast loginErrorToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Errore! login errato!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //new ReceiveToLogin().execute();

}
```

}

(The php code return a JSON line correct, when i use a browser to test it)

Thanks you.

Comment: ``permission.INTERNET`` is set in your app? Your catches miss a ``SecurityException``.

Comment: The `getErrorStream()` call probably returns `null` and you have a `NullPointerException`. The answers so far suggest to use the input stream which sounds like the right choice if your intention was to read the actual response from the server. If it's the error stream that you want to read, then check that it's not `null` before trying to read it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i post the part with an error, in the project i write bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

Comment: what do you get for `status`?

Comment: it is a line to try something thing I forgot to comment

Comment: Please use OKHttp library instead of HttpUrlConnection, it will help you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `conn.connect()` before getting stream.

```
conn.connect(); // connect before getting stream
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
```

Also you are returning `null` from `doInBackground` and you don't have a null check in `onPostExecute` which will cause `NullPointerException` on `reader = new JSONObject(result);` in case of exception in background.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    String result = s; // check null here.
    JSONObject reader = null;
```

Comment: ok, but the execution stop before return; it stops when there is `conn.getInputStreamReader()` without return error or exception

Comment: ok, thank you, but the problem rest: i'm add `conn.connect()` but I still have the problem;

Now the execution stops in this point. Why?

Comment: Where are you getting problem now? Have you returned result from doInBackground?

Comment: Have you set `internet permission` in manifest? Please post stack trace.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.luke.chatfinale">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: What exception are you getting now?

Comment: the problem is that i don't have an exception; the execution don't advance

Comment: You should check console for exceptions, and update the question with appropriate code and exception.

Comment: As URL i use this
`new SendToLogin(usrStr, pswStr, context).execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/test_x/login.php"); //localhost` 

and add ?username=usr&password=psw.

If i use port 8080 the execution termine at conn.connect(), instead if I  use port 80 the execution termine at `conn.getInputStreamReader()`

Comment: What's in your logcat?

Comment: Ok, i find the problem: the problem was `conn.setDoInput(true);`

Without this line, the execute is correct.

Thanks you all!

Comment: You have set it to true in the question

Answer (score 0):

i followed below code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) and its working fine for me

```
// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
// the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string.
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

See the console for response code and response

Answer (score 0):

1. `conn.getErrorStream()` should be `conn.getInputStream()` as stated @mallaudin
2. `super.onPostExecute(aVoid);` should be not commented. It should be `super.onPostExecute(s);`
3. In java string compare is like `query_result.toString().equals('ok')` not like `query_result.toString()=='ok'`
4. Can you log the `status` variable instead of comment?

Comment: Ok, i find the problem: the problem was `conn.setDoInput(true);` Without this line, the execute is correct.

Thanks you all!